Need a gear system to switch between 1:4, 1:6, and 1:14
I want to design a clock that lets me switch between 2 days per round, 3 days per round or 7 days per round. My main problem is I do not have the mechanical knowledge to develop it by myself and all systems I found where way to complicated for me to understand or to reproduce in the scale I need it. Any Ideas where to start, where to find maybe components that make it easier.
Best regards a design student

do you have access to some Lego with assorted gears?

no, but I could get some what is your idea?

and how do I use it for the switching part?

it will help with gaining mechanical knowledge ... also look at bicycle and automotive transmissions

Okay yeah thanks, but I don't have the time for learning by doing right now, I need a quick easy to understand explanation of the solution to my problem, in the end, I am a designer, not an engineer. I don't wanna go deep into the topic, just need an answer from an expert, or an evaluation if it is possible how I imagin it

A general understanding of gear systems is of course given, otherwise I couldn't have had the idea for my design. It's just that I do not want to invent a system that's already existing, or common to know by experts, if you have an idea or a specific clutch/gear system in mind that would help me don't hesitate to tell me

is this a school assignment?

How small are we talking about? A few cm or a few mm?

Seems easy enough. You need two parallel axles each with three gears.
If the separation of the axles is 1 unit of length, the diameters of the paired gears would be $\frac{2}{5} to \frac{8}{5}; \frac{2}{7} to \frac{12}{7} and \frac{2}{15} to \frac{28}{15}$
The gears could either be fixed at different heights so that one axle would have to be moved up or down to mesh the appropriate gears, or one set of gears could be free to rotate and the relevant gear held fast with a set screw as needed.
The size of the teeth would be different for each gear, but as the diameters match, so the number of teeth on each gear will match.
